# How can I enable kernel crash dumps in Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, crash, kernel, dump

I want to enable kernel crash dumps for my Debian 5.0.7 machine. The kernel version is 2.2.26 amd64.

How can I configure this?

Comment: I don't remember Kernel 2.2.x having AMD64 support... I this version number correct?

Answer (score 12):

You may also want to look at Debian's [`kdump-tools`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/kdump-tools) package to automate some of the necessary boot-time steps.

The steps are roughly,

1. `sudo apt-get install kdump-tools`
2. Set `USE_KDUMP=1` in `/etc/default/kdump-tools`
3. Add `crashkernel=128M` to the kernel command-line given in bootloader configuration (e.g. `/etc/default/grub`). It also doesn't hurt to pass `nmi_watchdog=1` as well to ensure that hard hangs are caught.

   - Note that 128MB is merely a ballpark figure. It needs to be large enough to accomodate the kernel image and the associated init ramdisk.
   - If your initram disk is large, you might be able to shrink it by tweaking `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`
4. Ensure that your boot loader configuration is updated (e.g. `sudo update-grub`)
5. Ensure your kernel is built with,

   - `CONFIG_RELOCATABLE=y`
   - `CONFIG_KEXEC=y`
   - `CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y`
   - `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`
6. Reboot
7. Verify that the crash kernel is loaded, `cat /sys/kernel/kexec_crash_loaded`
8. *Optional:* Test that all of this worked,

   1. `sudo sync; echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger`
   2. Use the `crash` tool to look at the resulting crash dump
9. Find a handle of good whiskey to ease the pain of your future in kernel debugging.

Comment: Upvote for the whisky reference. (And everything else).

Comment: It looks like manually adding "crashkernel" to the Grub configuration is no longer needed (at least in Debian 10). On doing so, I got a resulting commandline ending "crashkernel=256M quiet crashkernel=384M-:128M" - the second crashkernel parameter was added by something automatically

Answer (score 4):

A short answer, but...

Go to your kernel source (E.g. `cd /usr/src/linux/` ) and configure the options for the next kernel (`make menuconfig`). Go to "Processor type and features". Enable "kernel crash dumps". (`CONFIG_CRASH_DUMP=y`)

Build new kernel, install.

Then read these for more background information:
[Linux-Crash-HOWTO.pdf](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/Linux-Crash-HOWTO.pdf) and [lkcd utils](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/Linux-Crash-HOWTO/install.html)

Comment: And to check if it's already enabled:

`grep CONFIG_CRASH /boot/config-$(uname -r)`